# Is this a firefly?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, bioluminescence

[image]

It glows without interruption. This photo was taken near Barcelona, Spain.

Comment: It looks like a firefly to me. The fact that it glows is a dead give away, the light producing organ on the abdomen looks right, and the pronotum ( the shield covering the head ) also matches. Many species of firefly have flightless members ( usually female ) that sit on the ground and signal the flying ones.

Comment: My doubt comes from the fact that it glows without stop. In some identification charts that I've looked, they all glow in intervals of at most 9 seconds.

Comment: Glowing non-stop does seem weird. That would use up a lot of luciferase, and require a significant input of energy. But I'm pretty sure it's still a type of firefly, I'm not aware of any other bioluminescent beetles.

Comment: Looks like a glowworm to me.

Comment: @Federico I know it's been 9 months since this question was answered, but please see my new answer (Feb 2017)  addressing the geographic unlikelihood that your specimen is *L noctiluca*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your effort. I am definitely not an expert, but the map that you attach seems conclusive (the photographs are harder to distinguish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think @user137's [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/48338/16866) is close, but I believe that *Lampyris noctiluca* is the wrong species.

This looks like ***Lampyris iberica*** (the **Iberian Glow Worm**). The [*Lampyris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampyris) are a genus of european firefly beetles whose larvae and larviform females are among those organisms commonly called "glowworms".

[image]

<sup>© Prem Rose, 2016. http://www.inaturalist.org/photos/4351809</sup>

[image]

<sup>© Prem Rose, 2016. http://www.inaturalist.org/photos/4351808</sup>

These two species are very similar. According to [De Cock et al. (2014)](http://www.conference.ifas.ufl.edu/firefly/Poster%20Presentations/7%20-%20De%20Cock%20-%20Actualization%20of%20the%20Presence.pdf),

> Identification of Lampyris larvae stays difficult [due to a] lack of clear discriminating characteristics.

- See [here](http://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/Lampyris-iberica-cat11406.html) for more pictures of *L. iberica* (and [here](http://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/Lampyris-noctiluca-(Linnaeus-1767)-cat11397.html) for more pictures of *L. noctiluca* for comparison).

However, according to work presented by [De Cock et al. (2014)](http://www.conference.ifas.ufl.edu/firefly/Poster%20Presentations/7%20-%20De%20Cock%20-%20Actualization%20of%20the%20Presence.pdf), ***L. noctiluca* is not found in Barcelona, but *L. iberica* IS found in [Barcelona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Province_of_Barcelona).**

> *L. noctiluca* shows an extreme Northern distribution, only
>   present scattered over provinces in the North Atlantic region and Provinces in the Pyrenees, whereas ***L. iberica*** also occurs in
>   central Northern provinces and the Southern extreme of Spain in Cádiz and the province of Málaga.

[image]

Both species present a conspicuous sexual dimorphism, with males being smaller and winged and females being larviforme, without wings and noticeably larger than the males.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to guess this is a [Lampyris noctiluca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampyris_noctiluca), a species of firefly commonly found in Europe. The females are flightless, glow continuously for up to 2 hours, and are commonly referred to as glowworms, per anongoodnurse's comment.

[image]